# How can I assign a latitude and longitude to its corresponding place name in Google Places Api?

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I'm trying to make an app that shows users the nearest gyms.  So far, the app downloads the names and locations of the nearest gyms.  What I don't know how to do is assign the latitude and longitude to the place name that it belongs to.  When the json is output to the log, it comes out as:
place name
place coordinates
newPlaceName
newPlacecoordinates

How can I assign the coordinates to the place name so i can refer to them later?
Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
int REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
DownloadTask task;
Double lat;
Double lng;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    task = new DownloadTask();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null){



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        Log.e("Location info: Lat", lat.toString());
        Log.e("Location info: Lng", lng.toString());
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "damn",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     task.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + String.valueOf(lat) + "," + String.valueOf(lng) + "&radius=50000&type=gym&&key=MYAPIKEY");

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("Location info: Lat", lat.toString());
    Log.i("Location info: Lng", lng.toString());

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;


        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String weatherContent = jsonObject.getString("results");

            Log.i("gymresults", weatherContent);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(weatherContent);



            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("gymname", jsonPart.getString("name"));
                Log.i("gymlocation", jsonPart.getString("geometry"));



            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so you get the places names from google api , right. so i assume the names are all correctly spelled and are present on google maps.

if you satisfy the above condition then use the url to get place id for that name -

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=name_place_you_want_for_place_id&sensor=false&key=your_api_key

this url will give you place id in json . you have to parse and get the place id. you can check it first in browser too.

then use this url to get the latlng for that place id-

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=place_id_you_have&key=your_key

this will give you the latlng in json format.

there you go... you get what you wanted. let me know if this is what you wanted.